# Why didn't Nick Fury expose the villain's identity and plans?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

During *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, Fury learns that

> Mysterio is actually the "bad guy", and stages all the attacks on Earth.

He had, or could easily get, clear proofs, but even after the villain's death he does not go public with the evidence, leading to

> Spider-Man being accused of murdering Mysterio cold blooded (in the post-credit scene).

Why is this? What is his reasoning for not exposing the villain?

Comment: I believe that was the mid-credit scene, not the post one.

Comment: @PaulKaram I've heard about "mid-credit" scene, but didn't notice any. I'm pretty sure it was in the first (out of two) post-credit scene.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: after the scene you're describing, the scree goes black, and we see the names of a bunch of people who worked on the movie scrolling up. These are credits. “Post” means “after”. As the scene you're describing plays before the credits were finished, but after the initial (animated) credits, it's a mid-credits scene, because it's after some credits, but before some other credits — in other words, in the middle of the credits.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite oh. Well, I thought of it as two post-credits scenes, didn't make the distinction in my mind. But yes, you're correct, after re-reading the comment I understand.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: that's alright! [You're not the first to make the mistake](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216185/why-did-fury-respond-that-way#comment590894_216185)

Answer (score 15):

The people needed someone to believe in after Iron Man's death and most of the other heroes seemingly going AWOL. Mysterio filled that void and gave hope to those who needed it. Taking that hope and smashing it to pieces by revealing what happened is only going to make things worse and perhaps turn the people on themselves. Therefore, I would speculate they didn't reveal it initially because it was in the people's best interests.

Now though that Mysterio played his one last trick and made Spider-Man look like the bad guy and revealed his identity, they might explain what was going on and that Mysterio was the bad guy. However, as that was only shown in the post-credits scene and we don't have any future works, yet we will have to wait and see.

Also, the fact that Fury was off-world and Talos was impersonating him probably plays some part in it as Talos presumably has to get orders from Fury to act like that as we saw when he "calls" him up.

Comment: the last part says it

Comment: >There's always an Arquillian Battle Cruiser, or a Corillian Death Ray, or an intergalactic plague that is about to wipe out all life on this miserable little planet, and the only way these people can get on with their happy lives is that they DO NOT KNOW ABOUT IT!

Answer (score 7):

> Fury had, or could easily get, clear proof, but even after the villain's death he does not go public with the evidence.
>
> What is his reasoning for not exposing the villain?

### We don't know.

It's possible that Fury/Talos is in process of revealing the truth about Mysterio or, perhaps, not. These things have to be spun/managed after all. Mysterio caused a lot of international damage and one presumes that Fury was supposed to stop all that and being deceived would not inspire confidence.

We don't even know who Fury is supposed to be working for so there may be "reasons" why they don't want this information out in the public realm.